# Why does a multilanguage solution not work?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2008

My solution has a
C# application project
C# User Controls project
C++ Mathematics project

One of the UserControls uses function from the Mathematics (C++ project). This `UserControl` is used in the application.

Building and starting the application works just fine. When typing the IntelliSense suggests all the contained classes and methods. The `UserControl` appears correctly, but on clicking a button which calls the C++ function I get a `BadImageFormatException` (it pops out on the end of the automatically created Main function).

The help suggests to use `/fixed:no`  for linking, but that is already set up.

Comment: How are you importing the C++ function into the C# controls project?  Is there an exception message associated with the BadImageFormatException?

Comment: I use it like this: res = MathCpp.Math.Add(i1, i2);
There is a reference to MathCpp in the project. 
The message is: Cannot load file or assembly MathCpp, Version=1.0.3735.2560, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null or one of its dependent components. Tried to load program in wrong format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get BadImageFormatException when running a 32bit dll on a 64bit system. Try setting the target to "x86" on all your projects.

Comment: If you don't reference any native 32bit dlls I suppose you can: set the target to x64.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you are giving, it sounds like the managed code is trying to call into the C++ DLL as if it were managed code (and it is maybe built as unmanaged code).  The information about [BadImageFormatException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception.aspx) discusses this:

```
An attempt is made to load an unmanaged dynamic link library or executable (such as a Windows system DLL) as if it were a .NET Framework assembly.
```

If you are building the C++ project as unmanaged code, you may need to use p/invoke to call into it.